# Unary function chainer javascript

Tags: javascript

My task is to write a higher order function for chaining together a list of unary functions.The first argument is an array, which holds the names of functions to be called.The second param is the value to be used with functions. Here is the code

```
function square (x) {return x * x;}
function add3 (x) {return x + 3;}

   function chainer(a) {
     return function (b) {
       for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        return a[i](b)
        }
      }
   } 
  console.log(chainer([square, add3])(4));
```

The desired output is 19 but it executes only the first function and prints out 16. I think I would need to compose these functions somehow but can`t wrap my head around it. Would I need to use apply() or call() methods to complete the task? I am new to functional programming.

Comment: Oh, it is a typo, was in a hurry to type in. Already fixed. thanks for pointing out)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `return a[i](b)` *does* only call the first function and immediately return its result. You will need to put the `return` after the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b = a[i](b)
}
return b
```

---

Alternatively, this is a great use case for `reduce`/`fold` (which you probably have encountered before function composition):

```
return function(b) {
    return a.reduce(function(b, f) { return f(b) }, b)
};
```

or even

```
return a.reduce(compose, function id(x) { return x; });
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I thought there might be a problem with the scope. And yeah, I have seen those methods before. Great help! How would I use this method in reverse order? In for loop I could use "i--", is it possible to do it with reduce?